# How to pass parameters in Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes

The [Kubernetes document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md) have said:

> In the future we may want to introduce the following params: aggregator (max, min, 95th, etc.) and window (1h, 1d, 1w, etc.) which will allow to get the other aggregates over the custom time window.

How to pass the parameters in Kubernetes API?

I tried the following URL that it didn't work:
`http://localhost:8080/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods?window=1d`